# Actionsheet footer not getting exported in NativeBase

Tags: react-native, native-base, actionsheet

It seems that the ActionSheet footer is not exported using the latest release v4.0 of NativeBase.

Answer (score 0):

Footer and header were removed from the new version. It can easily be created using a Box component inside ActionSheet.Content